# Question about feature matrix and notation in the paper Implicit Under-Parameterization Inhibits Data-Efficient Deep Reinforcement Learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, papers

Let me know if this is not the place for this question. I'll take it down happily if that's the case. Also, I emailed the authors, but it seems like I won't be getting a response, so that's why I am here.

In the second paragraph of the preliminaries section almost at the end they have the following: "We refer the output of the penultimate layer of the deep Q-network as the learned feature matrix $\phi$, such that $Q(s,a)=w^T\phi(s,a)$, where $w\in R^d$ and $\phi\in \mathbb{R}^{|S||A|\times d}$.

- The matrix notation I am familiar with is such that if $A$ is a $m\times j$ matrix and $B$ is a $j\times n$ matrix, then $AB$ is a $m\times n$ matrix. According to the statement above $w^T\rightarrow 1\times d$ and $\phi\rightarrow|S||A|\times d$, then the dimensions would not match, unless $\phi\rightarrow d\times|S||A|$. What am I misunderstanding?
- Assuming fully connected layers, the output of a layer is a vector, so how is the feature matrix $\phi$ obtained from the output of the penultimate layer of the deep Q-network?

I'd appreciate if any can answer my questions and maybe share a code implementation of this paper. I have searched, but didn't find anything.

For reference, the paper can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.14498)

Comment: Instead of saying "Question about X" in the title, can you please just put your specific question in the title?

Comment: I will, but the question itself is not about a topic per se, but their paper and their notation. In other words, someone who hasn't looked at the paper could not answer the question.